# Outputting results as a table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset as follows:

```
print(df)

name      points    attempts
'Alex'      2          4
'Brian'     1          2
'Cathy'     3          5
'Daniel'    5          7
```

Let's say I have some code of the form

```
for name in df:
    if points > 2:
        grade = 'pass'
    else:
        grade = 'fail'

    average_points = points/attempts
    attempts_left = 10 - attempts
```

And what I am trying to achieve here is an output table (in a pandas dataframe) of the form

```
name        grade    average_points    attempts_left
'Alex'      fail          0.5               6
'Brian'     fail          0.5               8
'Cathy'     pass          0.6               5
'Daniel'    pass          0.71              3
```

Problem is, I am unsure of the return/append functions that I should employ in my code. Also, I am aware that it may be simpler to just add columns in my original dataset for 'grade', 'average_points' and 'attempts_left', but this approach does not work in my case as my raw data is more complicated than the working example above.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could vectorize your operations and use `assign`

```
In [839]: df.assign(attempts_left=10 - df.attempts,
     ...:           average_points=df.points / df.attempts,
     ...:           grade=np.where(df.points > 2, 'pass', 'fail'))
Out[839]:
       name  points  attempts  attempts_left  average_points grade
0    'Alex'       2         4              6        0.500000  fail
1   'Brian'       1         2              8        0.500000  fail
2   'Cathy'       3         5              5        0.600000  pass
3  'Daniel'       5         7              3        0.714286  pass
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, John! However, I am looking for something more along the lines of df2.append('grade'/'average_points'/'attempts_left') onto a new dataframe, with each name as a separate row. 


More about my raw_data: it is a timeseries index for all attempts for ONE player in a month. So in this case, I am actually trying to calculate the DAILY results of the player (grade, average_points, attempts_left) and outputting the table, with each row representing a day in the month.


Not sure if I was clear enough, so feel free to ask for more info. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.DataFrame()` and `df.append`:

```
df2 = pandas.DataFrame()
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    points = row["points"]
    attempts = row["attempts"]
    new_row = {}
    new_row["name"] = row["name"]
    if points > 2:
        new_row["grade"] = 'pass'
    else:
        new_row["grade"] = 'fail'

    new_row["average_points"] = points/attempts
    new_row["attempts_left"] = 10 - attempts
    df2 = df2.append(pandas.DataFrame(new_row,index=[i]))
print(df2)
```

Outputs:

```
   attempts_left  average_points grade    name
0              6        0.500000  fail    Alex
1              8        0.500000  fail   Brian
2              5        0.600000  pass   Cathy
3              3        0.714286  pass  Daniel
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Alex', 2, 4],
    ['Brian', 1, 2],
    ['Cathy', 3, 5],
    ['Daniel', 5, 7],
], columns=['name', 'points', 'attempts'])

df['grade'] = df['points'].apply(lambda points: 'pass' if points > 2 else 'fail')
df['attempts_left'] = df['points'].apply(lambda points: 'pass' if points > 2 else 'fail')
df['average_points'] = df[['points', 'attempts']].apply(lambda row: row['points']/row['attempts'], axis=1)

new_df = df[['name', 'grade', 'average_points', 'attempts_left']]
```